# MYSQL specific search

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to ORDER BY a MYSQL query correctly. I need the rand() to include the query with the shortest length, the query with the second shortest length, and the query with the third shortest length. Is there a way to do that with just MYSQL?

```
SELECT input FROM tableName WHERE input LIKE '%one%' ORDER BY length(input) ASC, rand() limit 1;

one
one one
one one one
one one one one
```

In this case, the query only include the rand() with the lowest length. So basically, I need the rand() to include the:

```
one
one one
one one one
```

So that it selects one of these randomly.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: You are ordering `ASC` (ascending) so the shortest comes first. You need to order `DESC` to get the longest

Comment: @ravi I edited the question.

Comment: why are you using rand() ??

Answer (score 0):

```
 order by length(input) asc limit 3;
```

It will return

```
one
one one
one one one
```